# jQuery uidatepicker buttonimage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, uidatepicker

I cannot get the buttonimage for the uidatepicker plugin for jquery to work:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
      {        
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
      }
);
```

I have the image in the right location (in a subdirectory named images)...what am I doing wrong?

Here is the link:

http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/sixthiteration/performanceanalysis.php

Comment: Try adding `buttonImageOnly: true` to it.

Comment: doesn't work-plus I want both to be triggers...:/

Comment: what browser are you using? 
In IE, does it show the [X] image holder where the button should be?
Can you paste the HTML you've used for the datepicker, please? also, does the datepicker show when you click on the textbox?

Comment: I am using safari and firefox, in both the images do not appear. See edit for the link.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? I could see the button image in Firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `showOn: "both"` and `buttonImageOnly: true` to stop the image looking like a button.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! (seems like a possible bug though, as the demo's on the JUI site don't use these settings?)(also, dunno why you didn't have any upvotes, so i gave you one :D )

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. But you can try this alternative.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "buttonImage", '/images/calendar.gif');
```

Comment: the thing is i have other attributes being set other than the above, will this not overwrite them? Things such as minDate, maxDate

Comment: It will only set the `buttonImage` property without impacting other properties. Try it.

Comment: is setting buttonImage ALL you have to do?

Comment: I have ...it didn't work..Plus, the documentation does it the way I have: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger